# Downloading PDF File with AJAX/MVC 3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, download

Basically the issue is this:

I have a pdf file that I am requesting from a server based on the currently logged in user's ID and the OID. In order to get the OID, I have to parse a value from a HTML table based on the button the user clicks on and then send it to the home controller. Then an API call is run to grab the OID. Another API call is then made with the OID to pull the PDF file. AJAX is used to send the the parsed HTML value to the home controller using this code here:

```
        $('.pdfPrint').live('click', function () {
            $(this).addClass('selectedDetails');
            var parent = $('.selectedDetails').parents('tr');
            var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
            var td = tr.children();
            var i = 0;
            td.each(function () {
                $(this).addClass('tdGrid' + i);
                i++;
            });
            var primaryReference = "";
            primaryReference = $('.tdGrid1').text();
            gridClassRemover();
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: { pReference: primaryReference }, // get the form data
                type: "POST", // GET or POST
                url: "/Home/PrintFromGrid", // the file to call
                success: function (response) { // on success..
                    callTrackDialog();
                    // update the DIV                         
                },  // end of success
                error: function () {
                    alert('An error has occurred. If this problem persists please contact support.');
                }
            });  // end of .ajax
        });
```

Comment: check out my post i did it..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550301/mvc3-ajax-beginform-post-download-file/11565983#11565983

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, don't use AJAX to download files. Simply redirect in javascript by passing the `pReference` as query string parameter:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("PrintFromGrid", "Home")?pReference=' + encodeURIComponent(primaryReference);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I don't understand though is how you would grab the pReference value and use that line of code all in 1 button click. Here's the current code edited up above on the op.

Comment: @Nozoku, in your AJAX code you seemed to already have it. The point of my answer is that you have it don't use AJAX, perform a redirect. And if this value is known on the server, don't bother with any javascript at all, simply use the Html.ActionLink helper.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this will work. I also forgot to mention I'm building this entire table manually along with all the buttons from Jquery...which is also making an Ajax call with an API call. So essentially this has to pull the value I need and then do the redirect in 1 button click.

Comment: @Nozoku, why do you think that this wouldn't work? In the click callback of the button simply put this `window.location.href` redirect. What is sure is that AJAX won't work for downloading files.

Comment: Do you have an example of a click call back?